# RadDataForm update example

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am looking for an example on the use of RadDataForm / Vue to update data in a vuex store. I have the data populating no problem, but I cannot find anywhere in the current documentation that explains how to trigger an update function when the data is updated.  here is a simple example, how would I trigger the save() function when the data is updated and I click done in the form?

````
  <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" backgroundColor="lightgray">
             <RadDataForm 
                :source="record"
                 />
   </StackLayout>
   <script>
    export default {
        data() {}
        },
        methods:{
         save(){
             console.log('save')
            }, 
        }
        computed:{
            record (){
                return this.$store.getters.record;
            }
        },
     };
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a watcher to a local property, i recommend using mapState from Vuex.

You can have something like this:

```
  computed: mapState({
    record: this.$store.getters.record;
  })
```

And also a watcher that sets a callback to a function, based on if a value has changed or not.

```
  watch: {
    record: function () {
     // something to run when record changes
    }
```

In summary, you have a local mapped variable from your store and a watcher that acts on whether the information has changed or not. Hope this helps

[See: MapState Helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)
[See: Computed properties and watchers](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

Comment: Thanks.  changed computed to record (state){...} per the link to get access to this.$store... but the watcher does not register the change.  I think the RadDataForm is not setting the change to the record object.  does the RadDataForm need an action or more?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.  This is not documented anywhere I can find in the nativescript/vue docs.  I found: [RadDataForm Commit Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/DataForm/GettingStarted/dataform-start-result).  So, using that, I modified to (keeping mapState from Luis.) I added:

v-on:propertyCommitted="save" to RadDataForm

So, this works:

```
 `<StackLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" backgroundColor="lightgray">
             <RadDataForm 
                :source="record"
                 v-on:propertyCommitted="save"/>
   </StackLayout>
   <script>
    export default {
        data() {}
        },
        methods:{
         save(){
             console.log('save')
            }, 
        }
        computed: mapState({
        record(state){
            return record = this.$store.getters.record;
        }
     };`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more detailed answer for this.  obviously, I would set the store value in the save function.

```
    <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" backgroundColor="lightgray">
             <RadDataForm 
                id="myDataForm"
                :source="record"
                 v-on:propertyCommitted="save"/>
   </StackLayout>
   <script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    import { getViewById } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view";
    export default {
        data() {}
        },
        methods:{
         save(){
            console.log('save')
            let data = args.object
            var dataform = getViewById(data, "myDataForm");
            console.log(dataform.editedObject)//<--updated Data Here
            }, 
        }
        computed: mapState({
        record(state){
            return record = this.$store.getters.record;
        }
     };
```